# Permanent of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Permanent of a linear transformation. I'm guessing that there is not as changing the basis would change it?

Is the permanent of a matrix changed by being acted on by change of basis matrices?

Comment: Did you try 2x2 matrices?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply pick a 2-by-2 matrix and change of coordinates at random (whatever your notion of randomness is), you see that permanent is not preserved. For instance, consider similar matrices
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
2&0\\
0&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
1&1
\end{array}\right].
$$